# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LineItemCreation: maximum trigger depth exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification, bulk

I have created two triggers to affect the opportunity line item and opprtunity. Keep getting thrown that error I'm assuming i haven't bulkified my trigger correctly, was wondering if someone could give me some advice on where im going wrong and how i should tackle it.

***LineItemCreation Trigger***

```
trigger LineItemCreation on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update) {

    Product2 productsRef = new Product2();
    Opportunity oppRef = new Opportunity();
    String oliIdd;
    Decimal OliDayPrice;
    Integer daysDiff;
    List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> OLISlist = new    List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem OLI :Trigger.new){

        OLIidd = OLI.Id;
        try{
            productsRef = [SELECT Id, Basis__c, Family FROM Product2 WHERE
                        Id =:OLI.Product2Id]; 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
             System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        oppRef = [SELECT Id, Contract_Start_Date__c, Go_Live_Date__c,
                              Contract_End_Date__c FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id=:OLI.OpportunityId];

        daysDiff = oppRef.Contract_Start_Date__c.daysBetween(oppRef.Contract_End_Date__c);

        System.Debug('DaysDifference = ' + daysDiff);
        OliDayPrice = (OLI.TotalPrice / daysDiff);
        System.Debug('Dailys Schedule Record Price = ' + oliDayPrice);

        Decimal totalPaid = 0;
    }

    for(Integer i=0; i < daysDiff; i++){

        if((productsRef.Basis__c =='Per Site Per Month' || productsRef.Basis__c =='Per Device Per Month') && productsRef.Family=='Licensing'){
                OpportunityLineItemSchedule OLISl = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule(
                OpportunityLineItemId=OLIidd,
                Revenue=OliDayPrice,
                ScheduleDate=(oppRef.Contract_Start_Date__c + i), //issue with it adding on revenue to saleprice
                Type='Revenue');
                OLISlist.add(OLISl);
        }   
    }

    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
        if(!OLISlist.isEmpty()){
            insert OLISlist;
            System.debug('List Inserted:' + OLISlist); 
        }
    }
}
```

***OpportunityUpdate Trigger***

```
trigger OpportunityUpdateTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {

    List<Product2> getProducts = new List<Product2>();
    List<Opportunity> oldOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> newOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> getSchedules = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();
    List<OpportunityLineItem> OLIlist = new  List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Date conStartNew;
    Date conStartOld;
    Date conEndNew;
    Date conEndOld;
    Date goLiveNew;
    Date goLiveOld;

    set<Id> getOLI = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> OLIid = new set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity old : trigger.old){
        //get oli and add to list
        conStartOld = old.Contract_Start_Date__c;
        conEndOld = old.Contract_End_Date__c;
        goLiveOld = old.Go_Live_Date__c;
        for(OpportunityLineItem OLI : [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE 
                                   OpportunityId=:old.Id]){
            getOLI.add(OLI.Product2Id);
            OLIid.add(OLI.Id);
            OLIlist.add(OLI); 

       }
       //GET PRODUCTS ADD TO LIST
       for(Product2 p : [SELECT Id, Basis__c, Family FROM Product2 WHERE 
                  Id=:getOLI AND Family='Licensing' AND (Basis__c='Per Device Per Month'
                  OR Basis__c='Per Site Per Month')]){

           getProducts.add(p);
           System.debug('products : ' + getProducts);

       }
       //GET ALL REVENUE SCHEDULES RELATED TO OLI
        for(OpportunityLineItemSchedule s : [SELECT Id, ScheduleDate FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule
                                     WHERE OpportunityLineItemId = :OLIid]){
            System.debug('OLI ID =' + OLIid);
            getSchedules.add(s);
            System.debug('Schedules =' + getSchedules);
        }
    }


    System.debug('s = ' + getSchedules);

    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new){
        conStartNew = o.Contract_Start_Date__c;
        conEndNew = o.Contract_End_Date__c;
        goLiveNew = o.Go_Live_Date__c;
    }

    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(conStartNew != conStartOld || goLiveNew != goLiveOld || conEndNew != conEndOld){
            System.debug('Date changed!');
            Delete getSchedules;
            System.debug('Schedules Removed');
            for(OpportunityLineItem x : [SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                         WHERE Id=:OLIid]){
                update x;    
            }   
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your code to provide consistent indenting. I can't overstate how important being consistent in indentation is to code readability.

Comment: The first thing I've noticed here is that you have a DML update inside of a loop at the end of `OpportunityUpdateTrigger`. Just like queries, DML should never appear inside of a loop. I doubt that alone is causing the max trigger depth error that you're seeing though. Are these the only triggers on the various Opportunity objects?

Comment: Thank you @Derek and yes these are the only two triggers I am using to automatically create opportunitylineschedules. Just confused at the minute, relatively new to apex is well which doesnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After staring at your triggers for a fair amount of time, I think I've come up with a plausible explanation.

### Background

The relationship between `OpportunityLineItem` (`OLI` for short) and `Opportunity` isn't quite a Master-Detail relationship (Salesforce does some funky stuff with standard objects), but it allows you to create rollup summary fields on `Opportunity` that summarize a field on `OpportunityLineItem`.

From the [documentation on trigger order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) (emphasis mine):

> 16. If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. **Parent record goes through save procedure**.

### The Problem

It breaks down to the fact that you have an implicit loop in your two triggers. An update to one updates the other.

So, say we're starting with an update to an `OLI`. Things run as expected, until we get to step 16 in the order of execution. Now, the parent `Opportunity` goes through a save, kicking off its trigger.

Where things go wrong is your `Opportunity` trigger then causes an update on `OLIs`. Thus, we have a loop, and it continues until you've hit the max trigger depth (16 levels of nested triggers, if memory serves).

### The Solution

The easiest way out of this problem is to remove the DML update of `OLIs` in your `Opportunity` trigger. This would cut the feedback loop, ensuring that your triggers only flow one way (i.e. from `OLI` to `Opportunity`). This probably isn't possible in your situation, as it appears that you're using dates on the `Opportunity` to drive logic on `OLI`.

The next easiest solution is to track which `OLIs` have already been updated using a separate apex class with a static `Set<Id>`.

The extra class only needs to be 3 lines long

```
public class OLITracker{
    public static Set<Id> alreadyUpdated = new Set<Id>();
}
```

The reason why this will work is that a static variable inside of a class will retain its data throughout the entire transaction (so if we set the data in the `OLI` trigger, it'll still be available in the `Opportunity` trigger). We must use a separate class for this, as static variables in triggers behave differently (and are nearly useless, imo).

Once you have that, you'll need to make the following changes to your triggers:

your OLI trigger

```
trigger LineItemCreation on OpportunityLineItem (after insert, after update) {

    Product2 productsRef = new Product2();
    Opportunity oppRef = new Opportunity();
    String oliIdd;
    Decimal OliDayPrice;
    Integer daysDiff;
    List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> OLISlist = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();
    
    // If this is an update, we want to note which OLIs we've seen.
    // We won't be using this information in this trigger, but it's important to 
    //   do this here.
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        OLITracker.alreadyUpdated.addAll(trigger.newMap.keySet());
    }

    // Code below here remains the same
}
```

and your Opportunity trigger

```
trigger OpportunityUpdateTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {

    // code before this point remains the same

    Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> olisToUpdate;
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(conStartNew != conStartOld || goLiveNew != goLiveOld || conEndNew != conEndOld){
            System.debug('Date changed!');
            Delete getSchedules;
            System.debug('Schedules Removed');

            // DML in a loop is as bad as a query in a loop.
            // Store the query in a map.
            // This will make it easy to remove the OLIs that have already been
            //   updated.
            olisToUpdate = new Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id=:OLIid]);

            // Removing a key from a map will remove the value for that key
            //   from the map as well.
            // This could be done in the query above, but it would require a
            //   'NOT IN', which I believe makes the query non-selective.
            // Doing things this way should never cause issues.
            olisToUpdate.keySet().removeAll(OLITracker.alreadyUpdated);

            // Finally, we can run the update.
            update olisToUpdate.values();
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough, your explanation and thoroughness is really appreciated ! I'll try this when i get in tomorrow, Thanks again :)